# Experiencing errors in The Rails Tutorial Chapter 8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

I tried fixing it but to no avail. I'm pretty sure I followed the tutorial. This happened in chapter 8 of The Rails Tutorial.

Here is the error when i run `bundle exec rake test`

```
ERROR["test_current_user_returns_nil_when_remember_digest_is_wrong", SessionsHelperTest, 2015-09-17 16:33:02 +0100]
 test_current_user_returns_nil_when_remember_digest_is_wrong#SessionsHelperTest (1442503982.53s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `user' for #<SessionsHelperTest:0xbdef3ba8>
        test/helpers/sessions_helper_test.rb:6:in `setup'
    test/helpers/sessions_helper_test.rb:6:in `setup'

ERROR["test_current_user_returns_right_user_when_session_is_nil", SessionsHelperTest, 2015-09-17 16:33:02 +0100]
 test_current_user_returns_right_user_when_session_is_nil#SessionsHelperTest (1442503982.55s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `user' for #<SessionsHelperTest:0xb9575274>
        test/helpers/sessions_helper_test.rb:6:in `setup'
    test/helpers/sessions_helper_test.rb:6:in `setup'

ERROR["test_login_with_remembering", UsersLoginTest, 2015-09-17 16:33:02 +0100]
 test_login_with_remembering#UsersLoginTest (1442503982.61s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `session' for nil:NilClass
        test/test_helper.rb:27:in `log_in_as'
        test/integration/users_login_test.rb:51:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'
    test/test_helper.rb:27:in `log_in_as'
    test/integration/users_login_test.rb:51:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'

ERROR["test_login_without_remembering", UsersLoginTest, 2015-09-17 16:33:02 +0100]
 test_login_without_remembering#UsersLoginTest (1442503982.73s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `session' for nil:NilClass
        test/test_helper.rb:27:in `log_in_as'
        test/integration/users_login_test.rb:56:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'
    test/test_helper.rb:27:in `log_in_as'
    test/integration/users_login_test.rb:56:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'

  28/28: [=======================================================================================================] 100% Time: 00:00:03, Time: 00:00:03

Finished in 3.29948s
28 tests, 62 assertions, 0 failures, 4 errors, 0 skips
```

test/test_helper.rb

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
    require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
    require 'rails/test_help'
    require "minitest/reporters"
    Minitest::Reporters.use!

    class ActiveSupport::TestCase
      # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
      fixtures :all

      # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...

      # Returns true if a test user is logged in.
      def is_logged_in?
        !session[:user_id].nil?
      end

      # Logs in a test user.
      def log_in_as(user, options = {})
        password    = options[:password]    || 'password'
        remember_me = options[:remember_me] || '1'
        if integration_test?
          post login_path, session: { email:        user.email,
                                      password:     password,
                                      remember_me:  remember_me }
        else
          session[:user_id] = user.user_id  # this is line 27
        end
      end

      private

        # Returns true inside an integration test.
        def integration_test?
          defined?(post_via_reditect)
        end
    end
```

test/helpers/sessions_helper.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

    class SessionsHelperTest < ActionView::TestCase

      def setup
        @user = user(:microte) # Line 6
        remember(@user)
      end

      test "current_user returns right user when session is nil" do
        assert_equal @user, current_user
        assert is_logged_in?
      end

      test "current_user returns nil when remember digest is wrong" do
        @user.update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(User.new_token))
        assert_nil current_user
      end
    end
```

test/integration/users_login_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

    class UsersLoginTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
      def setup
        @user = users(:microte)
      end

      test "login with invalid information" do
        get login_path
        assert_template 'sessions/new'
        post login_path session: { email: "", password: "" }
        assert_template 'sessions/new'
        assert_not flash.empty?
        get root_path
        assert flash.empty?
      end

      test "login with valid information" do
        get login_path
        post login_path, session: { email: @user.email, password: 'password' }
        assert_redirected_to @user
        follow_redirect!
        assert_template 'users/show'
        assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path, count: 0
        assert_select  "a[href=?]", logout_path
        assert_select  "a[href=?]", user_path(@user)
      end

      test "login with valid information follwed by logout" do
        get login_path
        post login_path, session: { email: @user.email, password: 'password' }
        assert is_logged_in?
        assert_redirected_to @user
        follow_redirect!
        assert_template 'users/show'
        assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path, count: 0
        assert_select  "a[href=?]", logout_path
        assert_select  "a[href=?]", user_path(@user)
        delete logout_path
        assert_not is_logged_in?
        assert_redirected_to root_url
        # Simulate a user clicking logout in a second window
        delete logout_path
        follow_redirect!
        assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path
        assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path, count: 0
        assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user), count: 0
      end

      test "login with remembering" do
        log_in_as(@user, remember_me: '1') # Line 51
        assert_not_nil cookies['remember_token']
      end

      test "login without remembering" do
        log_in_as(@user, remember_me: '0') # Line 56
        assert_nil cookies['remember_token']
      end
    end
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the first two errors are in your session_helper: your setup defines `@user = user(:microte)`.

Not sure about the errors in the remembering tests are; the tests you've shared appear to be fine. I suggest you compare the code changes against what's in the tutorial to see what the cause of these errors are.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are getting an error when trying to pull out a `user` from your fixtures. Check your `fixtures/users.yml` file and see if you have a `microte` user defined. It should look something like this(just an example):

```
microte:
  name: "Test User"
  email: "test_user@example.com"
  password_digest: <%= User.digest("password")%>
  slug: <%= "Test User".parameterize %>
  activated: true
```

Answer (score 0):

In the tutorial the user provided is named :michael
As others before me have noted, you wrote :microte instead.
Check in your users.yml fixture how you named him there, and make sure they match.

As a bit of explanation: in the beginning of your test there is a setup method that prepares your test setting:

```
 def setup
    @user = users(:microte)
  end
```

the user you are instantiating here, is put into the fixtures file.